# Wireless cards went dead

Tags: 12.04, wireless, drivers

It is my first time posting here and I want to thank you in advance for your time :).

Well, so I will try to describe my problem...
I am currently running Kubuntu 12.04 LTS on a Toshiba laptop.
I have an internal Realtek RTL8723AE wireless card for which I have built and installed the drivers for my kernel and which used to work fine until now.
I also have an external TP-LINK TL-WN722N wireless card which used to be autodetected by the system up to now and there was no problem whatsoever. This card has an Atheros chipset.

Strange as it may sound, my problems began after using the TP-LINK card on a Windows 7 machine. After making it work there - installing the drivers and so on - I pulled it and went to use it on my laptop again. I can't explain why, but it didn't work there anymore. It is not recognized by the system at all. I certainly did not do anything stupid in the meantime. I then thought "this must be some evil Bill Gates curse". I mean, I tried not to be supersitious etc, but I still haven't found a more reasonable explanation.

Anyway, I started to search the internet and I found some answers related to this card. I tried some of them, but they didn't work. The last try I gave was this post [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/98844/how-do-i-get-a-tp-link-tl-wn722n-wireless-card-working). After doing that, I rebooted the laptop.
When my OS loaded I could not see the card in my network manager (same as after the "Bill Gates curse"), but now my internal card had disappeared as well... I tried to reinstall its drivers but nothing happened... This is the point where I am at now. I don' t really know what to do. Any help will be greately appreciated :).

(English is not my native language, so please excuse any mistakes)

---

These are the results from the wireless_script after fixing the issue with the internal card:

```
########## wireless info START ##########

##### release #####

Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 12.04.4 LTS
Release:    12.04
Codename:   precise

##### kernel #####

Linux matrix 3.2.0-58-generic #88-Ubuntu SMP Tue Dec 3 17:37:58 UTC 2013 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux

##### lspci #####

08:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8723AE PCIe Wireless Network Adapter [10ec:8723]
    Subsystem: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. Device [10ec:0723]
    Kernel driver in use: rtl8723e

09:00.0 Ethernet controller [0200]: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8101E/RTL8102E PCI Express Fast Ethernet controller [10ec:8136] (rev 05)
    Subsystem: Toshiba America Info Systems Device [1179:fb37]
    Kernel driver in use: r8169

##### lsusb #####

Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 003 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 004 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 8087:0024 Intel Corp. Integrated Rate Matching Hub
Bus 002 Device 002: ID 8087:0024 Intel Corp. Integrated Rate Matching Hub
Bus 003 Device 002: ID 046d:c05f Logitech, Inc. 
Bus 003 Device 003: ID 0930:021d Toshiba Corp. 
Bus 001 Device 003: ID 04f2:b307 Chicony Electronics Co., Ltd 
Bus 003 Device 004: ID 0cf3:9271 Atheros Communications, Inc. AR9271 802.11n

##### PCMCIA Card Info #####

##### rfkill #####

0: hci0: Bluetooth
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: no
1: phy0: Wireless LAN
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: no

##### lsmod #####

ath9k_htc              92738  0 
ath9k_common           14053  1 ath9k_htc
ath9k_hw              411239  2 ath9k_htc,ath9k_common
ath                    24067  3 ath9k_htc,ath9k_common,ath9k_hw
rtl8723e              175439  0 
rtlwifi               118798  1 rtl8723e
mac80211              506862  3 ath9k_htc,rtl8723e,rtlwifi
cfg80211              205774  4 ath9k_htc,ath,rtlwifi,mac80211

##### iw reg get #####

country 00:
    (2402 - 2472 @ 40), (3, 20)
    (2457 - 2482 @ 20), (3, 20), PASSIVE-SCAN, NO-IBSS
    (2474 - 2494 @ 20), (3, 20), NO-OFDM, PASSIVE-SCAN, NO-IBSS
    (5170 - 5250 @ 40), (3, 20), PASSIVE-SCAN, NO-IBSS
    (5735 - 5835 @ 40), (3, 20), PASSIVE-SCAN, NO-IBSS

##### interfaces #####

auto lo
iface lo inet loopback

##### iwconfig #####

wlan0     IEEE 802.11bgn  ESSID:"AP_AMYNTAIO_U8"  
          Mode:Managed  Frequency:2.427 GHz  Access Point: <MAC address removed>   
          Bit Rate=11 Mb/s   Tx-Power=20 dBm   
          Retry  long limit:7   RTS thr=2347 B   Fragment thr:off
          Power Management:off
          Link Quality=16/70  Signal level=-94 dBm  
          Rx invalid nwid:0  Rx invalid crypt:0  Rx invalid frag:0
          Tx excessive retries:0  Invalid misc:696   Missed beacon:0

##### route #####

Kernel IP routing table
Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags Metric Ref    Use Iface
0.0.0.0         192.168.150.1   0.0.0.0         UG    0      0        0 wlan0
169.254.0.0     0.0.0.0         255.255.0.0     U     1000   0        0 wlan0
192.168.122.0   0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U     0      0        0 virbr0
192.168.150.0   0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U     2      0        0 wlan0

##### resolv.conf #####

nameserver 127.0.0.1

##### nm-tool #####

NetworkManager Tool

State: connected (global)

- Device: eth0 -----------------------------------------------------------------
  Type:              Wired
  Driver:            r8169
  State:             unavailable
  Default:           no
  HW Address:        <MAC address removed>

  Capabilities:
    Carrier Detect:  yes

  Wired Properties
    Carrier:         off

- Device: wlan0  [AP_AMYNTAIO_U8] ----------------------------------------------
  Type:              802.11 WiFi
  Driver:            rtl8723e
  State:             connected
  Default:           yes
  HW Address:        <MAC address removed>

  Capabilities:
    Speed:           11 Mb/s

  Wireless Properties
    WEP Encryption:  yes
    WPA Encryption:  yes
    WPA2 Encryption: yes

  Wireless Access Points (* = current AP)
    CYTA717589:      Infra, <MAC address removed>, Freq 2437 MHz, Rate 54 Mb/s, Strength 26 WPA2
    *AP_AMYNTAIO_U8: Infra, <MAC address removed>, Freq 2427 MHz, Rate 11 Mb/s, Strength 32

  IPv4 Settings:
    Address:         192.168.150.44
    Prefix:          24 (255.255.255.0)
    Gateway:         192.168.150.1

    DNS:             195.170.0.1
    DNS:             195.170.2.2

##### NetworkManager.state #####

[main]
NetworkingEnabled=true
WirelessEnabled=true
WWANEnabled=true
WimaxEnabled=true

##### NetworkManager.conf #####

[main]
plugins=ifupdown,keyfile
dns=dnsmasq

[ifupdown]
managed=false

##### iwlist #####

wlan0     Scan completed :
          Cell 01 - Address: <MAC address removed>
                    Channel:4
                    Frequency:2.427 GHz (Channel 4)
                    Quality=16/70  Signal level=-94 dBm  
                    Encryption key:off
                    ESSID:"AP_AMYNTAIO_U8"
                    Bit Rates:1 Mb/s; 2 Mb/s; 5.5 Mb/s; 11 Mb/s
                    Mode:Master
                    Extra:tsf=000000000f456648
                    Extra: Last beacon: 532ms ago
                    IE: Unknown: 000E41505F414D594E5441494F5F5538
                    IE: Unknown: 010482040B16
                    IE: Unknown: 030104
                    IE: Unknown: DD2A000C42000000011E000000002E660902FF0F776C616E5F4F4D4E49000000000000000000000005027B09
          Cell 02 - Address: <MAC address removed>
                    Channel:4
                    Frequency:2.427 GHz (Channel 4)
                    Quality=18/70  Signal level=-92 dBm  
                    Encryption key:on
                    ESSID:""
                    Bit Rates:1 Mb/s; 2 Mb/s; 5.5 Mb/s; 11 Mb/s
                    Mode:Master
                    Extra:tsf=000000000f456186
                    Extra: Last beacon: 532ms ago
                    IE: Unknown: 0000
                    IE: Unknown: 010482040B16
                    IE: Unknown: 030104
                    IE: Unknown: 050400010000
                    IE: IEEE 802.11i/WPA2 Version 1
                        Group Cipher : TKIP
                        Pairwise Ciphers (1) : TKIP
                        Authentication Suites (1) : PSK
                    IE: Unknown: DD2A000C42000000011E000000002E660902FF0F776C616E5F4F4D4E49000000000000000000000005027B09
          Cell 03 - Address: <MAC address removed>
                    Channel:6
                    Frequency:2.437 GHz (Channel 6)
                    Quality=14/70  Signal level=-96 dBm  
                    Encryption key:on
                    ESSID:"CYTA717589"
                    Bit Rates:1 Mb/s; 2 Mb/s; 5.5 Mb/s; 11 Mb/s; 18 Mb/s
                              24 Mb/s; 36 Mb/s; 54 Mb/s
                    Bit Rates:6 Mb/s; 9 Mb/s; 12 Mb/s; 48 Mb/s
                    Mode:Master
                    Extra:tsf=00000000e7338193
                    Extra: Last beacon: 848ms ago
                    IE: Unknown: 000A43595441373137353839
                    IE: Unknown: 010882848B962430486C
                    IE: Unknown: 030106
                    IE: Unknown: 0706475220010D14
                    IE: Unknown: 2A0100
                    IE: Unknown: 2F0100
                    IE: IEEE 802.11i/WPA2 Version 1
                        Group Cipher : CCMP
                        Pairwise Ciphers (1) : CCMP
                        Authentication Suites (1) : PSK
                    IE: Unknown: 32040C121860
                    IE: Unknown: 2D1A7C181BFFFF000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
                    IE: Unknown: 3D1606080000000000000000000000000000000000000000
                    IE: Unknown: DD090010180200F02C0000
                    IE: Unknown: DD180050F2020101000003A4000027A4000042435E0062322F00

##### iwlist channel #####

wlan0     13 channels in total; available frequencies :
          Channel 01 : 2.412 GHz
          Channel 02 : 2.417 GHz
          Channel 03 : 2.422 GHz
          Channel 04 : 2.427 GHz
          Channel 05 : 2.432 GHz
          Channel 06 : 2.437 GHz
          Channel 07 : 2.442 GHz
          Channel 08 : 2.447 GHz
          Channel 09 : 2.452 GHz
          Channel 10 : 2.457 GHz
          Channel 11 : 2.462 GHz
          Channel 12 : 2.467 GHz
          Channel 13 : 2.472 GHz
          Current Frequency:2.427 GHz (Channel 4)

##### modinfo #####

filename:       /lib/modules/3.2.0-58-generic/kernel/drivers/net/wireless/ath/ath9k/ath9k_htc.ko
firmware:       htc_9271.fw
firmware:       htc_7010.fw
description:    Atheros driver 802.11n HTC based wireless devices
license:        Dual BSD/GPL
author:         Atheros Communications
srcversion:     C7C7DD7D23ED5C73A328E72
alias:          usb:v0CF3p20FFd*dc*dsc*dp*ic*isc*ip*
alias:          usb:v0411p017Fd*dc*dsc*dp*ic*isc*ip*
alias:          usb:v083ApA704d*dc*dsc*dp*ic*isc*ip*
alias:          usb:v0846p9018d*dc*dsc*dp*ic*isc*ip*
alias:          usb:v0CF3p7010d*dc*dsc*dp*ic*isc*ip*
alias:          usb:v1668p1200d*dc*dsc*dp*ic*isc*ip*
alias:          usb:v0CF3p7015d*dc*dsc*dp*ic*isc*ip*
alias:          usb:v057Cp8403d*dc*dsc*dp*ic*isc*ip*
alias:          usb:v0CF3pB003d*dc*dsc*dp*ic*isc*ip*
alias:          usb:v040Dp3801d*dc*dsc*dp*ic*isc*ip*
alias:          usb:v04CAp4605d*dc*dsc*dp*ic*isc*ip*
alias:          usb:v13D3p3350d*dc*dsc*dp*ic*isc*ip*
alias:          usb:v13D3p3349d*dc*dsc*dp*ic*isc*ip*
alias:          usb:v13D3p3348d*dc*dsc*dp*ic*isc*ip*
alias:          usb:v13D3p3346d*dc*dsc*dp*ic*isc*ip*
alias:          usb:v13D3p3328d*dc*dsc*dp*ic*isc*ip*
alias:          usb:v13D3p3327d*dc*dsc*dp*ic*isc*ip*
alias:          usb:v07D1p3A10d*dc*dsc*dp*ic*isc*ip*
alias:          usb:v0846p9030d*dc*dsc*dp*ic*isc*ip*
alias:          usb:v0CF3p1006d*dc*dsc*dp*ic*isc*ip*
alias:          usb:v0CF3p9271d*dc*dsc*dp*ic*isc*ip*
depends:        ath9k_hw,ath9k_common,mac80211,ath,cfg80211
intree:         Y
vermagic:       3.2.0-58-generic SMP mod_unload modversions 
parm:           debug:Debugging mask (uint)
parm:           nohwcrypt:Disable hardware encryption (int)

filename:       /lib/modules/3.2.0-58-generic/kernel/drivers/net/wireless/ath/ath9k/ath9k_common.ko
license:        Dual BSD/GPL
description:    Shared library for Atheros wireless 802.11n LAN cards.
author:         Atheros Communications
srcversion:     87C8338518A200F45D72110
depends:        ath,ath9k_hw
intree:         Y
vermagic:       3.2.0-58-generic SMP mod_unload modversions 

filename:       /lib/modules/3.2.0-58-generic/kernel/drivers/net/wireless/ath/ath9k/ath9k_hw.ko
license:        Dual BSD/GPL
description:    Support for Atheros 802.11n wireless LAN cards.
author:         Atheros Communications
srcversion:     5A4F26731216C44D9DA1D5C
depends:        ath
intree:         Y
vermagic:       3.2.0-58-generic SMP mod_unload modversions 
parm:           force_new_ani:Force new ANI for AR5008, AR9001, AR9002 (int)

filename:       /lib/modules/3.2.0-58-generic/kernel/drivers/net/wireless/ath/ath.ko
license:        Dual BSD/GPL
description:    Shared library for Atheros wireless LAN cards.
author:         Atheros Communications
srcversion:     8B429DBE4586F4065E2EA2E
depends:        cfg80211
intree:         Y
vermagic:       3.2.0-58-generic SMP mod_unload modversions 

filename:       /lib/modules/3.2.0-58-generic/kernel/drivers/net/wireless/rtlwifi/rtl8723e/rtl8723e.ko
firmware:       rtlwifi/rtl8723efw.bin
description:    Realtek 8723E 802.11n PCI wireless
license:        GPL
author:         Realtek WlanFAE <wlanfae@realtek.com>
author:         lizhaoming  <chaoming_li@realsil.com.cn>
srcversion:     161CC0CE5CE8DD8F90D732E
alias:          pci:v000010ECd00008723sv*sd*bc*sc*i*
depends:        mac80211,rtlwifi
vermagic:       3.2.0-58-generic SMP mod_unload modversions 
parm:           swlps:bool
parm:           swenc:using hardware crypto (default 0 [hardware])
 (bool)
parm:           ips:using no link power save (default 1 is open)
 (bool)
parm:           fwlps:using linked fw control power save (default 1 is open)
 (bool)

filename:       /lib/modules/3.2.0-58-generic/kernel/drivers/net/wireless/rtlwifi/rtlwifi.ko
description:    Realtek 802.11n PCI wireless core
license:        GPL
author:         Larry Finger    <Larry.FInger@lwfinger.net>
author:         Realtek WlanFAE <wlanfae@realtek.com>
author:         lizhaoming  <chaoming_li@realsil.com.cn>
srcversion:     5EE6168D1B4BBA473F6CCD0
depends:        cfg80211,mac80211
vermagic:       3.2.0-58-generic SMP mod_unload modversions 

##### modules #####

lp
rtc
fuse

##### blacklist #####

[/etc/modprobe.d/blacklist-ath_pci.conf]
blacklist ath_pci

[/etc/modprobe.d/blacklist.conf]
blacklist evbug
blacklist usbmouse
blacklist usbkbd
blacklist eepro100
blacklist de4x5
blacklist eth1394
blacklist snd_intel8x0m
blacklist snd_aw2
blacklist i2c_i801
blacklist prism54
blacklist bcm43xx
blacklist garmin_gps
blacklist asus_acpi
blacklist snd_pcsp
blacklist pcspkr
blacklist amd76x_edac

[/etc/modprobe.d/blacklist-fglrx.conf]
blacklist radeon

##### udev rules #####

# PCI device 0x10ec:/sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1c.2/0000:09:00.0 (r8169)
SUBSYSTEM=="net", ACTION=="add", DRIVERS=="?*", ATTR{address}=="<MAC address removed>", ATTR{dev_id}=="0x0", ATTR{type}=="1", KERNEL=="eth*", NAME="eth0"

# PCI device 0x10ec:/sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1c.1/0000:08:00.0 (rtl8723e)
SUBSYSTEM=="net", ACTION=="add", DRIVERS=="?*", ATTR{address}=="<MAC address removed>", ATTR{dev_id}=="0x0", ATTR{type}=="1", KERNEL=="wlan*", NAME="wlan0"

# PCI device 0x10ec:/sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1c.1/0000:08:00.0 (rtl8723e)
SUBSYSTEM=="net", ACTION=="add", DRIVERS=="?*", ATTR{address}=="<MAC address removed>", ATTR{dev_id}=="0x0", ATTR{type}=="1", KERNEL=="wlan*", NAME="wlan1"

# PCI device 0x10ec:/sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1c.1/0000:08:00.0 (rtl8723e)
SUBSYSTEM=="net", ACTION=="add", DRIVERS=="?*", ATTR{address}=="<MAC address removed>", ATTR{dev_id}=="0x0", ATTR{type}=="1", KERNEL=="wlan*", NAME="wlan2"

# PCI device 0x10ec:/sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1c.1/0000:08:00.0 (rtl8723e)
SUBSYSTEM=="net", ACTION=="add", DRIVERS=="?*", ATTR{address}=="<MAC address removed>", ATTR{dev_id}=="0x0", ATTR{type}=="1", KERNEL=="wlan*", NAME="wlan3"

# USB device 0x0cf3:0x9271 (usb)
SUBSYSTEM=="net", ACTION=="add", DRIVERS=="?*", ATTR{address}=="<MAC address removed>", ATTR{dev_id}=="0x0", ATTR{type}=="1", KERNEL=="wlan*", NAME="wlan4"

##### dmesg #####

[   14.655533] rtl8723e 0000:08:00.0: PCI INT A -> GSI 17 (level, low) -> IRQ 17
[   14.655546] rtl8723e 0000:08:00.0: setting latency timer to 64
[   14.672901] firemare: rtl8723fw_B.bin
[   14.891443] ieee80211 phy0: Selected rate control algorithm 'rtl_rc'
[   14.891781] rtlwifi: wireless switch is on
[   17.341662] ADDRCONF(NETDEV_UP): wlan0: link is not ready
[   17.341975] ADDRCONF(NETDEV_UP): wlan0: link is not ready
[   22.463671] wlan0: authenticate with <MAC address removed> (try 1)
[   22.465525] wlan0: authenticated
[   22.498231] wlan0: associate with <MAC address removed> (try 1)
[   22.501926] wlan0: RX AssocResp from <MAC address removed> (capab=0x421 status=0 aid=2)
[   22.501932] wlan0: associated
[   22.502823] ADDRCONF(NETDEV_CHANGE): wlan0: link becomes ready
[   29.489752] rtlwifi-0:rtl_watchdog_wq_callback():<0-0> AP off, try to reconnect now
[   29.489803] wlan0: Connection to AP <MAC address removed> lost.
[   30.931440] wlan0: authenticate with <MAC address removed> (try 1)
[   30.933533] wlan0: authenticated
[   30.933740] wlan0: associate with <MAC address removed> (try 1)
[   30.939057] wlan0: RX ReassocResp from <MAC address removed> (capab=0x421 status=0 aid=2)
[   30.939060] wlan0: associated
[   33.474061] wlan0: no IPv6 routers present
[   53.562982] usb 3-2: ath9k_htc: Transferred FW: htc_9271.fw, size: 51272
[   53.565886] usb 3-2: ath9k_htc: Unable to allocate URBs
[   53.565908] ath9k_htc: probe of 3-2:1.0 failed with error -22
[   53.565935] usbcore: registered new interface driver ath9k_htc

########## wireless info END ############
```

I also reinstalled the kernel but the issue with TP-LINK remained.

Comment: Please run the script that is in the accepted answer in the link below so we may see the information needed to help diagnose the issue.
<http://askubuntu.com/questions/425155/my-wireless-wifi-connection-does-not-work-what-can-i-do>

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I have run the script and pasted the results [here](http://pastebin.ubuntu.com/7937829/)

Comment: Did you compile this driver yourself and was it from backports? link please? if you did when there is a kernel upgrade you have to install it again.

Comment: I can't recall where I got the driver... (I believe you refer to the Realtek card) but there were no kernel updates. The Realtek card stopped being recognized after I built and installed the latest ath9k_htc driver I found [here](http://www.orbit-lab.org/kernel/compat-wireless-3.0-stable/v3.6/compat-wireless-3.6.8-1.tar.bz2)

Comment: Shutdown your computer and unplug usb wireless device then boot up and run `sudo modprobe -v rtl8723e` post any errors.

Comment: I have already tried that. There were no errors, but nothing happened as well.

Comment: You ran the command with the -v in it while the usb was uplugged after being shutdown? there should have been errors or in `lsmod` you should see the driver loaded.

Comment: No, excuse me, I tried to load another module. It is way past bedtime here (in Greece)... 
It says: "FATAL: Module rtl18723e not found."

Comment: We can start tomorrow if you would like but tomorrow afternoon I am leaving town so I will be on less.

Comment: Yes, great, thanks for your interest and time. We can continue tomorrow. All the best.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do:

```
sudo apt-get install --reinstall linux-headers-$(uname -r) build-essential
```

Download [chili555 driver](https://dl.dropbox.com/u/58267392/rtl_92ce_92se_92de_8723ae_linux_mac80211_0007.0809.2012.tar.gz)

Then do:

```
cd Desktop /rtl_92ce_92se_92de_8723ae_linux_mac80211_0007.0809 .2012  
sudo su
make
make install
modprobe rtl8723e
exit
```

Any time there is an update to the kernel you will have to do:

```
cd Desktop /rtl_92ce_92se_92de_8723ae_linux_mac80211_0007.0809 .2012  
sudo su
make clean
make
make install
modprobe rtl8723e
exit
```

A Reboot may be needed.

Comment: Thanks a lot. The driver you included is newer than the one I had. I first uninstalled the compat-wireless-3.6.8.1, then I compiled and installed the chili555 driver. The internal wireless card is working again (and seems to have a better signal now). TP-LINK is still unrecognizable.

Comment: Ok, I got the TP-LINK working too (I didn't do anything amazing, I just tried another usb port). It looks like that it can only be recognized on USB3. Is this some sort of microsoft voodoo :)? Do you know if it is possible to make it run on USB2 as well? For me, it is ok, since it's working again...

Comment: I am not sure if it can use usb3 but I would think it should be able too. Does anything else work in that usb port? Only one question is allowed per question so please accept this one so everyone can benefit from it and if you still need help start a new question for the other device.

Comment: All my usb ports (2 USB2 + 1 USB3) work fine. The only problem is that TP-LINK does not work on the USB2 ports, while it used to (it only works on the USB3 one). This happened after I used it on a windows 7 pc. Maybe there were updates on the firmware of the device..? I can't really tell. Anyway, thanks a lot. I will mark the answer as the accepted one.